# What does it mean ''Unconfirmed change may be issued''?

Tags: address, change

After i send some BTC the left over BTC came back and goes to a new Address in my Wallet, how come ? What does it mean ''Unconfirmed change may be issued'' ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there "Change" in Bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96822/why-is-there-change-in-bitcoins)

Comment: i am just confused coz the unspend came always back to the same address as far i remember, but this time a new address was taken from my Wallet

Comment: Which wallet are you using?