Please explain this weird bitcoin transaction
I am an EVM blockchain engineer and I started learning Bitcoin few days ago.
this is my friend's address of bitcoin wallet: bc1pfatr7dvkz65y6p6xxv84anesttxc7q9etez8em5uyvll5kk8atpqrx3r2s
and what makes me confused is a transaction in his history. https://mempool.space/address/bc1pfatr7dvkz65y6p6xxv84anesttxc7q9etez8em5uyvll5kk8atpqrx3r2s

the very first transaction is understandable.
there was no transactions before first transaction and bc1q7pcfjas8swacpwnmm5d4s679jffn3lawkm89kv sent some amount of BTC to this wallet. (It's okay)
but the next transaction is strange.

1.where these inputs come from?
BTW please explain this output as well.
2. why there are two outputs that is same as wallet address?

3. and what is the meaning of this green button?

I am looking forward to kind help of community members.
please make me clarify this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Related topic: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/96822/5406

1.where these inputs come from?
One single Bitcoin transaction can have multiple inputs and multiple outputs. Multiple Bitcoin from different addresses can be spent as inputs in one single transaction, and one single transaction can send Bitcoin to multiple addresses(outputs).
2. why there are two outputs that is same as wallet address?
It's allowed to have two outputs with the same address in single transaction.
3. and what is the meaning of this green button?
It means the output Bitcoin is not yet spent, so it's UTXO(Unspent Transaction Output).
